# Approximate asymptotic behavior

Tags: approximation, factorial, infinity

Let be $n$ and $k, (k\le \frac{n}{2}) $ positive integers.
I am trying to show that the expression:
$$
p(k) = \frac{n!}{2^n(\frac{n}{2} + k)! \hspace{0.1cm} (\frac{n}{2} - k)!} $$
reduces to:
$$ p(0) \hspace{0.1cm} e^{-\frac{2 \hspace{0.1cm} k^2}{n}} $$
when $n$ tends to infinity.
I lost myself trying to use Stirling approximation...
have you any idea about the direction I should go?

Comment: Is $n$ supposed to be even ?

Comment: Are we assuming $n\gg k  \ge 1$ or $n \gg k \gg 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get lost in Stirling's approximation, it can be helpful to instead use the logarithmic form
$$
\ln n! \approx n\ln n - n+\frac{\ln n}{2} +\frac{\ln 2\pi}{2} + O(n^{-1}),
$$
then look at each of the three terms separately to find cancellations. Anyways, now let's look at a variation on the original equation,
$$
-\ln\frac{p(2n,k)}{p(2n,0)} = \ln (n-k)!+\ln (n+k)!-2\ln n!
$$
We then use the log form of Stirling's approximation and simplify to get
\begin{eqnarray}
-\ln\frac{p(2n,k)}{p(2n,0)} 
 &\approx& \left[ (n-k)\ln(n-k)+(n+k)\ln(n+k)-2n \ln n\right]+ \left[ \frac{\ln(n-k)+\ln(n+k)-2\ln n}{2}\right]\\
&\approx& n\left[\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\ln\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)+\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right) \right] + \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1 -\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right) 
\end{eqnarray}
Now, before we continue, we need to make sure we didn't make the error term relevant. The error terms are all of the form $c n^{-m}$, and $(n-k)^{-m}+(n+k)^{-m}-2n^{-m}\sim m(m+1)k^2/n^{m+2} = O(n^{-m-2})$. So the leading term is $O(n^{-3})$ and we'll be fine as long as we don't have cancellations down to that order. Using the small argument approximation for the logs gives
$$
-\ln\frac{p(2n,k)}{p(2n,0)}  = \frac{k^2}{n}-\frac{k^2}{2n^2}+O(n^{-3}),
$$
and indeed we have terms above $O(n^{-3})$. Now, to get this as an approximation of $p(n,k)$, we drop the $n^{-2}$ term and do a bit of algebra to get
$$
p(n,k) \approx p(n,0)e^{-2k^2/n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Some hand-waving that can probably be formalized more rigorously:

For fixed $k$ while $n \to \infty$,
\begin{align}
\frac{p(k)}{p(0)}
&= \frac{(n/2)! (n/2)!}{(n/2 + k)! (n/2 - k)!}
\\
&\sim \frac{(n/2)^{n+1}}{(n/2 + k)^{n/2 + k + 1/2} (n/2 - k)^{n/2 - k + 1/2}}
& \text{Stirling}
\\
&= \frac{1}{(1 + 2k/n)^{n/2 + k + 1/2} (1 - 2k/n)^{n/2 - k + 1/2}}
\\
&\sim e^{-(2k/n)(n/2 + k + 1/2)} e^{(2k/n)(n/2 - k + 1/2)}
& \text{$(1+1/m)^m \to e$}
\\
&= e^{-4k^2/n}
\end{align}

Not sure why I have a $4$ instead of $2$, maybe I made an error somewhere.

Comment: OK, but $(1+2k/n)^{n/2+k+1/2} -> e^k$, no? I am confused with your second `~`...